# lightning:datatable link to sObject

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datatable

Do you have to use the url data type to navigate to a sObject like how it is on list views?

For example, this is the data table which I want to refactor to use the base datatable lightning component:

[image]

We are using an HTML table with slds styling currently. I try to avoid hard coding urls when possible but it doesn't seem like this is possible currently. Am I missing something or is that how it is done.

Answer (score 2):

As of [Summer '18](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_components_navigation.htm), you can use [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) to navigate to a SObject record or other pages within Salesforce without having to hardcode URLs.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found is to use window.location.origin to get the protocol and hostname, something like this:

```
oppty.link= window.location.origin + '/one/one.app#/sObject/' + oppty.Id + '/view';
```

The only problem that I see with this solution is the Critical Update about Lightning URL format change.. but if you already activate it, then it should work until the next URL format change.